# What are useful API's for/with generics?

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics

I'm looking for some code and API's that would show use use of generic in larger scheme of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit vague. Generics doesn't add anything to design patterns. They just adds [compile time type safety](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Fundamentals.html#What%20is%20the%20benefit%20of%20using%20Java%20generics?) to your code.

Probably your question needs to be reformulated as "What are useful API's for/with generics?". In that case, the [Java Collections API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) and [Java Concurrent API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) have nice examples.

Answer (score 2):

For some real-world examples, check out the [Java Collections framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) trail.  It's a pretty sane implementation, all things considered.

Comment: I would focus less on "design patterns" as generics are focused more on type safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195) with examples of GoF design-patterns as they appear in Java SE and Java EE.

Comment: Have a look at the ones referring to java.util Collection/List/Set/Map and their subtypes.